# Call javascript function from inserting script tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a function that I'm trying to call from a script tag

```
function foundElement(){
  console.log(' in found element')
}

var ele = document.createElement("script")
ele.textContent = "foundElement()"
document.head.appendChild(ele)
```

I'm getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: foundElement is not defined`. However, when I use the console the function is defined. Attached is a screenshot.

How can I call foundElement() by inserting a script tag?

[image]

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) everyone has to guess at random and that's bad. My guesses would be 1) you're not doing this in the content script, or 2) that site defines the function after the content script runs.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function foundElement() {
  console.log(' in found element')
}

var ele = document.createElement("script")
ele.textContent = "foundElement()"
document.head.appendChild(ele)
```

Works like a charm. Can you describe your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Content script JS and page JS are running in a different context with different permissions. The only thing they are sharing is DOM. You can found more details [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world)

If you need to share functions between Content-Script and page context - you need to inject function to the page too.

Example:

```
var fn = function injectedFunction(seed) { console.log(seed,Math.random());}
var ele = document.createElement("script");
ele.textContent = fn+"console.log(injectedFunction(document.location));";
document.body.appendChild(ele);
```